# Is there a way to have colored text on MS Command Prompt and/or Linux Terminal?

Tags: console, terminal, command-prompt

For the sake of readability, I'd like to know if there is a simple way to color parts of the text you output to a console. Both Linux Terminal and MS Command Prompt suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ANSI escape codes in Unix like OS. Here's the theory about manipulating colors: http://tldr.es/1md

In Windows, there's [console functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API.

Comment: Do you know if I can somehow make Windows command prompt work more like the Unix terminal and support those colors without using console functions?

Comment: There's device driver called ANSI.SYS that provides support for some ANSI escape symbols: http://bquot.com/xg Note: this device isn't enabled by default.

Comment: You're coming up to being two decades out of date with that `ANSI.SYS` suggestion.  Read the page that you yourself pointed to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the sequence: [{attribute};{foreground};{background}m using the color codes.
[This](http://linuxgazette.net/issue65/padala.html) explains it more precisely.

EDIT: For the list of the colors and an output of how they look go [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors).